# Custom error message for invalid datetime format using flask wtform DateTimeField

Tags: forms, python-3.x, datetime, flask, flask-wtforms

I want to get a custom error message when the given datetime format is incorrect.

The form class:

```
class NewShift(Form):
    start_date = DateTimeField(u'start-date', validators=[DataRequired("Start must be specified")], format='%d.%m.%Y %H.%M')
    end_date = DateTimeField(u'end-date', validators=[DataRequired("End must be specified")], format='%d.%m.%Y %H.%M') # ...
```

The view:

```
def new_shift():
    form = NewShift(request.form)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if not form.validate():
            print(form.errors)
            return render_template("add_shift.html", form=form, success=False)
        else:
            return render_template("add_shift.html", form=form, success=True)
```

Now the problem is that if the `DateTimeField()` contains an incorrect datetime format, I get the error message from the `DataRequired()` function. How can I specify a custom error message for this case?

Answer (score 2):

I looked through WTForms' documentation and came up with nothing, so my suggestion is do a StringField with custom validator instead, like:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError

class NewShift(FlaskForm):
    start = StringField(u'Up and At Them')
    end = StringField(u'Another Day in the Office')

    def validate_start(form, field):
        try:
            datetime.strptime(field.data, '%d.%m.%Y %H.%M')
        except Exception:
            raise ValidationError('Wrong Input Format!')
    def validate_end(form, field):
        try:
            datetime.strptime(field.data, '%d.%m.%Y %H.%M')
        except Exception:
            raise ValidationError('Wrong Input Format!')
```

Then when you want to store the data, just do a strptime.